# Control space between in-line list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to create a navigation menu at the top of the page, but the images are spaced too far away from each other and then they wrap.  How do I bring them closer together?

[image: bad spacing]

CSS:

```
 .weddingMenuIcon{
        width:30%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <img src="~/images/home.svg" class="img-responsive weddingMenuIcon" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/images/home.svg" class="img-responsive weddingMenuIcon" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/images/home.svg" class="img-responsive weddingMenuIcon" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually I believe we're missing other CSS that is styling that sort of behavior.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was simply changing the width from using percentage to using fixed pixel width.

Answer (score 0):

If I were building this as a centered navigation I would apply `inline: block` to the list items and then use a margin to define the spacing between them.

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hf1kra0d/1/)

```
.list-inline li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 40px; /* Items have 40px spacing between */
}
```